# Kotlin Map Serialization and Deserialization error class with map objects

Tags: kotlin, serialization, amazon-dynamodb, deserialization, mapper

I'm trying to create serialize and deserialize an object. I'm doing on this way:

```
   var mapper = ObjectMapper()

   var stringTest =   mapper.writeValueAsString(stringContainsObjectFilter);
    
   val raw: Any = mapper.readValue(stringTest, Any::class.java)
   val filtersFromString = mapper.convertValue(raw, ObjectFilter::class.java)

   val objectFilters = ObjectFilter()
   quoteFilters.rosterLine= filtersFromString.rosterLine
   quoteFilters.outOfPocketMax = filtersFromString.outOfPocketMax
   quoteFilters.cost = filtersFromString.cost
```

This is the class that I want to serialize and deserialize

```
open  class ObjectFilter{

    var rosterLine: Map<RosterEnum, List<Int>>? = null

    var outOfPocketMax: Map<String?, List<Int>>? = null

    var monthlyCost: List<MonthlyCost>? = null

}
```

But I'm getting the following message:

```
"Response[ObjectFilters]; could not unconvert attribute"
```

Can anyone help me please? I've been trying to solve it without result :(

Comment: In which line do you get that error? And why is `objectFilters` used before it is declared?

Comment: Also, I see both `ObjectFilter` and `ObjectFilters`, which seems odd.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelPiefel , I had the error on the `mapper.convertvalue`, I changed to that and I wrote as you can see in my answer. Thanks for your time reading my question.

Comment: You may want to create your mapper with `val mapper = ObjectMapper().registerKotlinModule()`

Comment: Yes, it could be a solution, I'm going to try. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, this is what I did and it worked:

```
val rawResult = mapper.convertValue(mapper.readValue(string, Any::class.java), Any::class.java)
        val filtersFromString = rawResult  as? ObjectFilter ?: ObjectFilter()
```

Comment: What does `convertValue()` do? Convert from `Any` to `Any`? Why do you not pass the expected class to `readValue()` in the first place? And, since you are using Kotlin, you might try to use `mapper.readValue<ObjectFilter>(string)`.

Comment: Hi @MichaelPiefel, what it does is to convert the value from mapper.read, I tried to not use any in the ::class.java, but I was getting an exception that said that mapper was unable to cast my class when I specified the name of it, so the only solution that worked for me was the one that I wrote.